# C # and C ++ Library (FILE * Type)

Tags: c#, c++

There is a project in C# and a library written in C++. In this library, the FILE * type is used in functions. If I import the library in C#, how can I use these functions? Are there any .NET tools to solve the problem?

Comment: I think you need to show some code of the _specific_ problem you have. Normally handles and pointers can be transfered through C# as `IntPtr`. Are you asking how to obtain the `FILE*` handle in the first place? Which method exactly do you want to use?

Comment: Just the same tool you already want to use, you'll have to pinvoke fopen() and fclose() to manage the FILE*.  If you have no idea what runtime library you need to use then talking to the library owner is always the best idea.

Comment: @René Vogt , For example library libbde(https://github.com/libyal/libbde) provides .DLL library, which contains function:
    LIBBDE_EXTERN    
int libbde_notify_set_stream( FILE *stream, libbde_error_t **error );
How I can use the function in C#?

Comment: That function that takes a `FILE*` assumes the caller is using the exact same compiler that was used to create the DLL.  The internals of `FILE` will differ between compIlers, so I don't see how you're going to get around that fact using C#.  There needs to be an indirect way of calling that function  without explicitly using `FILE *`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, agree, but may be exist .net tools to solve this problem or replace the type... :(

Comment: Forget it.  Functions taking a FILE*, are designed to work only for C++ and C, and for the specific compiler /build options.  Again, unless you factor the usage of FILE out, you cannot reliably use C# for this.